# Jtable with scrollpane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

how can I create a Jtable with Jscrollpane where vertical scroller should appear only after 2nd row and horizontal one should appear only after 3rd column i.e. first two row and first 3 columns should always be visible.

Answer (score 1):

The standard Swing JTable component does not support such a configuration. You can try splitting your component into three different JTables (one for the visible rows, one for the visible columns and another for the scrollable part) and synchronize the scrolling of the three of them programmatically.